# C# tcp sockets defining clients

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, networkstream

I'm trying to setup a tcp .net socket network with Visual Studio 2010. So far it works I can connect clients up to it but currently I have no way of defining the clients that are connected. I need like an array of clients that are connected so I can be more specific about who i streamWrite to.

This is my server code I am copying all of this from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511814/Multi-client-per-one-server-socket-programming-in

SERVER CODE

```
static TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(25000);

    static void Listeners()
    {
        Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
        if (socketForClient.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client:"+socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint+" now connected to server.");
            NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);

            System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);


            Console.WriteLine("type your message to be recieved by client:");
            string theString2 = Console.ReadLine();
            streamWriter.WriteLine(theString2);
            Console.WriteLine(theString2);
            streamWriter.Flush();

            while (true)
            {
                string theString = streamReader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Message recieved by client:" + theString);
                if (theString == "exit")
                    break;
            }
            streamReader.Close();
            networkStream.Close();
            streamWriter.Close();


        }
        socketForClient.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit from server program");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        tcpListener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("************This is Server program************");
        Console.WriteLine("Hoe many clients are going to connect to this server?:");
        int numberOfClientsYouNeedToConnect = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClientsYouNeedToConnect; i++)
        {
            Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listeners));
            newThread.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but why don't you just add the "socketForClient" to a list when it is accepted by the listener? And then remove it when the client sends "exit" and the socket is closed

Comment: Just realized that the example you're looking at has a terrible threading solution. You should look for a better tutorial, there are tons of them out there.

Comment: Are you developing both ends? Have you had a look at some of the available tools to avoid all the hassle?

Comment: Like @Fishy said, this code is horrible. Don't build on it, find a better tutorial. Anyway all you seem to need to do is save the Socket from `Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket()`, for example in a `List<Socket>`.

Comment: But then you're still stuck with thread/messaging handling on the server side. I'd say 'Don't build on this concept'.

Comment: Hi sorry for my delay. I'm trying to set this up for an XNA game that i'm working on. I'm not new to C# but i'm pretty new to .net sockets. So I don't really know if this is bad code or not it works and compared to most other examples iv downloaded this is nice and simple that's why it appealed to me.

Comment: That's totally understandable @DanSmith, we've all been there. Check this tutorial out, it shows a much better approach (imo) http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server

Comment: If you're doing this for a game, have a look at Lindgren - it's specifically tailored for game development, and it's a lot easier to use than raw sockets. If you decide to stick to raw sockets / `TcpClient` and friends, have a look at asynchronous I/O - this avoids the need for threads entirely, and it's pretty easy to manage client-specific state when using `await`. Have a look at my (WIP) sample - http://tinyurl.com/lunetworking-2, it shows a simple TCP chat client/server system using `await`-based APIs.

Comment: FIshySwede Thank's for the tutorial i'm just reading through it now this looks easy enough to understand for a beginner like me. Luaan I have looked at Lidgren and played around with it. I agree it definitely makes networking simple but I'm keen to have a go at trying to use sockets.

Comment: @FishySwede Thank you so much for that tutorial iv just managed to set it up. And it's working great. I found that one of the main problems I was having was I never used try and catch. Which is what caused my client to freeze a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to raw TCP Sockets, then you could pass a delegate/handler etc to the thread:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClientsYouNeedToConnect; i++)
{
     Thread newThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Listeners));
     newThread.Start(i);
}
```

Your listener then needs to take an `object` to match the `ParametrizedThreadStart` [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, if you are developing both ends (as I commented) I'd suggest something more abstract like [ASP.NET SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) or similar for such a scenario. It adds a bit overhead, but you get Server-To-Client and vice versa communication on a conveniently abstractioned level.